# How to process very large arff datasets using weka in java

Tags: java, hadoop, machine-learning, weka

I am trying to run a J48 classifier using weka in java. I am getting memory out of exception and gc_error. I tried debugging and I noticed its with reading the arff file,

```
 d = new DataInputStream(fs.open(new Path(filePath)));
                  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(d));
                  arff = new ArffReader(reader, 100000);
                  data = arff.getStructure();
                  data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
                  System.out.println("====add each line");
                  // Add each line to the input stream
                  while ((inst = arff.readInstance(data)) != null) {            
                      //inst.setDataset(data);  
 data.add(inst);             
                  }
                    System.out.println("close reader");     
                  reader.close();
```

Here, when i use data.add(inst), the "close reader" wont be printed and i used to get gc_error so i searched for online help and it was mentioned to use inst.setDataset(data) but after i did that mappers wont work and it directly gets reduced.

Comment: Add -Xmx2048m while running the program, if you have about 4gb ram, or change accordingly.

Comment: I tried doing that, but its of no use. As even dataset of size 200 mb is not running.